# User Management in Graph Databases

Tags: database, user-interface, graph, playframework-2.0, neo4j

I am trying to make a web app that uses PlayFramework2 and Neo4j Graph Database.My web app going to include user system.Users can add their visited places as nodes and traverse.My question; is it okay for keeping passwords and other personal information in nodes for authentication or using table based another database is better for login to web app.If all work can be done using Neo4j, what should be the structure of the user system in graph database for security.I am newbie at these jobs so, sorry if it is a absurd question.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can use neo4j to store user information.

As on all databases, be careful with some data, don't store password without a hash/crypt method !

If your datas are sensible,  you should well configure your neo4j instance to not allow remote connection, and why not implement some user role for connection.
See here : http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html

Answer (score 1):

You should either use one of the modern auth mechanisms like OAuth2 or at least strongly hash and salt the passwords with a long salt.